# How was this image designed?

Tags: images, photoshop-effects, effects, line-art

I've just came across a image with a peculiar effect. I'm not sure how they have hidden the original image in the lines(or layer perhaps?)

There has been no visible changes in color nor in the pattern of lines. So, how exactly did they embed the original image between the lines?

And Is there any way I could achieve the same effect using Photoshop?

***Image:***

[image]

*The hidden image can be viewed by a steady up and down scrolling*

P.S. I'm a beginner in Photoshop.

Comment: For those that have trouble seeing the image clearly it is best to squint heavily and look away from the image until it comes into view.

Comment: @AdamCaviness It's also easier, in my opinion, to see it while scrolling.

Comment: This is actually hurting my eyes, congratulations!

Comment: @TrivisionZero lol, it's just a fuzzy image :)

Comment: @SnazzySanoj On my phone it makes everything look blurry after, on my computer it just hurts :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some changes in color. Tts difficult to see with naked eyes but if you import you object to photoshop and use eyedroper you can see some color variations.

How you can achieve this effect:

1. Create the pattern(There are lots of ways to create this if you don't want to create this manually). You can change the color of upper and lower strips

[image]

1. Now put the image below the Patter (make sure the image is black) and Rasterize both (pattern and Image layer)
2. Now if you can see the original image, the pattern is little bit thicker where the panda shade lies. So, to do this, the easiest thing we can do is -
3. Select all the black region of your pattern [(CTRL + Click on the pattern layer thumbnail or Go to SELECT > Color Range > and select black color(increase the fuzziness to a higher value so it can select both shades of black)]
4. Now, Go to SELECT > MODIFY > EXPAND > and enter the value of 1px.
5. Now, Invert your selection (CTRL + SHIFT + I) go to the Image layer and hit Delete. It will delete all the unwanted area and will leave behind a thickness or 1px at the border. that's it.

Here's is my result

[image]
**You can zoom out the image to see the proper result.**

**Note:** Make sure you are creating this in high resolution(in my case I have created this in file size of 1350x1920px) So, 1px expansion worked for me.

Comment: In the original, the blend mode is probably set to screen or the blend options have been played with a bit—the bits of the superimposed image that are on the white areas are completely transparent, at any rate.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet the white are not completely transparent if import the image in photoshop and use eyedropper you can see some variation in colors

Comment: Okay, maybe not completely transparent—but definitely a lot more than in the one in your answer, where they’re just light grey and clearly visible.

Comment: It's definitely more complicated than either of the suggestions. Upon closer inspection the lines are just the same colour (not entirely black / white only due to compression noise) but **thicker** where the shade lies.

Comment: @ Vašek Potoček I must say you have an eye of eagle. I tried your suggestion(thicker where the shade lies) and yeah it worked 
here's the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/e81o9udbhkr6wz1/Test2.png?dl=0
if you zoom out the image you can see the result(I have added just 1px of thickness)

Comment: @Rishab I tried and got like the one in the answer, but couldn't make it like the one you did in the dropbox image. What exactly should I make change of?

Comment: @Snazzy Sanoj I will edit my answer with that one within 3-4 hours when I get back home

Comment: @Snazzy Sanoj I have edited my answer with the one I did with the image in the dropbox

Comment: Well, the answer totally changed in explanation, but the first sentence is still misleading.

Answer (score 6):

The bars in the pattern are actually not of exactly the same width. Some bars are slightly thicker, adding a darker mean shade to the image in that location. This way the picture is visible by just a slightly darker mean color (like 50% brightness for the bright regions and 52% brightness for the darker regions).

You can do this in photoshop, if you start with a gradiented pattern, eg. you create the bar fence as smooth transitions between black and white instead of sharp bars.

You then blend the target picture over that with only some percent and merge it down, to have the soft pattern attenuated a little bit by the  picture.

Last step is to use threshold to regain an b/w image.

As the blended picture modulated the brightness slightly, the threshold cut more or less of the bar width and so modulates the bar width.

Comment: The soft bar fence may be created by bluring a sharp fence, however this may lead to uneven thickness and rounded corners.